# Is it possible to have two versions of the same app on appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, publishing

I have an app for iPhone on app store that supports all versions from iOS 4.2.
Now I've developed the universal app (iPhone and iPad) that supports versions from iOS 5.0

Is it possible to have this two versions published on app store on the same page as one app and that the users are able to choose which version to install on their devices?

Comment: whats ur point for having 2 different versions on app store ? U have specific features for ios 4.2 in one and for ios 5.0 in other ?

Comment: Exactly they have different features, and also the last app is universal for iPhone and iPad

Comment: If they have actual different feature sets, then they should be 2 different apps.  Apple has occasionally allowed Legacy, "Lite" and "HD"-type apps if the apps are sufficiently different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not do that. A new binary in a application replaces the old one. Creating two applications in iTunesConnect is possible, but you need to name them uniquely, so you will have two different applications in the store.

Answer (score 4):

Since Apple released the App Store Review Guidelines, one of them is that developers should not "spam" the app store with multiple versions of the same app with minor changes.

What Apple wants from you right now is to merge all your apps into one. Put all the news sources in one app, and let the user decide which to read. You can write code to disable and/or hide other news sources that the user doesn't want to see.

Or, as Apple said, if you want to charge for each individual news source, then use In-App purchase to control access to each news source.

If you are charging, I won't get into the legality of charging people to read news that you don't own - I'm sure you've considered that.

Source: App Store Review Guidelines

2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

Answer (score 3):

Apple just announced that developers will be able to manage multiple versions of the same applications and make them available to customers if they want to go back.

Comment: how is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

But you can mix your 5.0 and 4.2 code and check all methods/class/frameworks that are not present in 4.2 to provide an alternative code.

There are many ways to check that, take a look at : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html

If you need some 5.0 frameworks, you can set them from required to optional and check in your code if you have access to them.